# Sending file via Intent fails Samsung 4.0.4

Tags: android, android-intent, uri

I have this set of code that works perfectly on every Android device I have....except for a Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 (go figure).  This code is designed to send a log file to me for debugging purposes.

When I try to share the file to Gmail it say 'Couldn't attach file'

Google Drive crashes when I try to share it to that.

Superbeam says the file you are trying to attach doesn't exist.

Sharing via bluetooth just fails

```
public static void sendLogs(Context ctx) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { ctx.getString(R.string.logs_email_receiver) });
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, ctx.getString(R.string.logs_email_title));

        Uri fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(ctx, "com.app.test", getFile(ctx));
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileUri);
        ctx.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, ctx.getString(R.string.logs_chooser_title)));
    }

private static File getFile(Context ctx) {
    return new File(ctx.getFilesDir(), log_name);
}
```

I feel like it's a Samsung bug , the fileUri is the same though.  The flags both exist since API 1, I don't know what else it could be.

Comment: You might try blending in [my `LegacyCompatCursorWrapper`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider#usage-legacycompatcursorwrapper), which helps to work around issues with buggy `ContentProvider` clients. [This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ContentProvider/V4FileProvider) demonstrates its use.

Comment: Oddly enough, if I setData(fileUri), it works but then inserts the URI in the to: section (but only for this device, other devices are unaffected).   Might just roll with this and let the user realize that invalid email has to be deleted since the valid email address is inserted as well.

Comment: `ACTION_SEND` does not use `setData()`.

Comment: You are correct. It's not supposed to. But that doesn't change the fact that setting the data causes it to work.